# Cannot start IntelliJ (2017.2.2)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, windows-7-x64, intellij-17

Everytime I try to run IntelliJ on windows 7, I get this error:

Internal error. Please report to http://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndex'
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:210)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1.a(MainImpl.java:64)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:345)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndex'
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:275)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:510)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:118)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.a(ApplicationImpl.java:475)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:548)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:493)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:482)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:102)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:434)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:420)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:203)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.intellij.util.indexing.ID
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.versions.KotlinMetadataVersionIndexBase.getName(KotlinMetadataVersionIndexBase.kt:37)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl$FileIndexDataInitialization.<init>(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:2272)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.initComponent(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:320)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:492)
    ... 32 more
```

I have reinstalled and restarted several times. I am stuck using this version as my company does not allow any other versions.

Comment: Please re-download from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download and reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

Having `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.intellij.util.indexing.ID` I'd say you have corrupted distribution.